# select and display an image from a dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, directory

I have a php code that has a dropdown menu filled with the names of images files in a specific folder, what i want is once the user select one of the names the selected image is displayed, at the moment i'm trying to use a submit button.
i am trying to not use jquery or other languages

```
   <?php


$folder = 'C:\Users\source\\';

  echo '<form action="" method="post">'."\n".'<select name="image">'."\n".
 dropdown(image_filenames($folder), @$_POST['image']).
 '</select>'."\n".'<input type="submit" name="submit">'."\n".'
 </form>';
function image_filenames($dir)
{
  $handle = @opendir($dir)
    or die("I cannot open the directory '<b>$dir</b>' for reading.");
$images = array();
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
{
    if (preg_match('/^.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg)$/', $file))
    {
        $images[] = $file;
    }
}
closedir($handle);
return $images;
}
function dropdown($options_array, $selected = null)
{
$return = null;
foreach($options_array as $option)
{
    $return .= '<option value="'.$option.'"'.
               (($option == $selected) ? ' selected="selected"' : null ).
               '>'.$option.'</option>'."\n";
}
return $return;
}


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

echo '<img src=C:\Users\source'. $row['images'] . ' />';



}
   ?>
```

Comment: You're going to need javascript if you want the images to show up without reloading the page.

Comment: You forgot to put quotes around your `src` property in the `img` tag. Other than that, what exactly is the problem? Do you get an error or does the code simply not execute what you want? If so, then what *does* happen?

Comment: once i press the submit button it just load the icon of an image instead of the image, i think the problem is in the naming i use

Comment: `$row` it comes from where...???

Comment: Are you getting expected results when you call on the `image_filenames($dir)` without the use of your form? Single that function out and try to load a $dir with it that you know is good, do you get anything? `var_dump(image_filenames($dir));`

Comment: actually no, i've just tried to load an image directly from html and is still giving me just the icon

Comment: interestingly, I have tested the function on my computer and it returns a valid var_dump of the folder I set as $dir. So you know the function is good.

Comment: How are you using the dropdown function? Are you dynamically parsing the directory and then creating buttons for each image?

Comment: Okay are you on a local server? You may have read/write protection on the file path to the image and/or directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must need to keep your file inside your project ...

**change**

```
$folder = 'C:\Users\source\\';
```

**to**

```
$folder = 'images\\';
```

*images* is the folder name which inside your project...

xampp or wampp not consider the local path files...

And it won't display the images as well...

**Hope this Helpful...**

I have changed **two places** in your code...

```
 <?php


    $folder = 'images\\'; // changed here

      echo '<form action="" method="post">'."\n".'<select name="image">'."\n".
     dropdown(image_filenames($folder), @$_POST['image']).
     '</select>'."\n".'<input type="submit" name="submit">'."\n".'
     </form>';
    function image_filenames($dir)
    {
      $handle = @opendir($dir)
        or die("I cannot open the directory '<b>$dir</b>' for reading.");
    $images = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
        if (preg_match('/^.*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg)$/', $file))
        {
            $images[] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
    return $images;
    }
    function dropdown($options_array, $selected = null)
    {
    $return = null;
    foreach($options_array as $option)
    {
        $return .= '<option value="'.$option.'"'.
                   (($option == $selected) ? ' selected="selected"' : null ).
                   '>'.$option.'</option>'."\n";
    }
    return $return;
    }


    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    echo '<img src=images\\'. $_POST['image'] . ' />';  // changed here



    }
       ?>
```

Comment: just tried, it is reading the path of the file fine but it is still not loading the image

Comment: this worked perfectly, i just put all the images in the folder where the program is and it is working thanks